# Chaining ES6 Promises in Mongoose using React-Redux APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I have several models:**

1. **CountryModel**  - no references,
2. **PersonModel**  - has a phone_id reference,
3. **PhoneModel**   - has a country_code reference

With the code below, I have been able to seed PhoneModel with a country_code reference, *but when I attempt to push the phone_ids, afterwards, into the PersonModel, the array is always empty.*

**What do I need to change in code below to retain the phone_ids in the person document?**

```
import * as commonPhone from '../../_common/communication/phone.common.actions.api';

function seedDatabase() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    PersonModel.find({}, (errFind, collection) => {
      if (errFind) {
        console.log(`${PersonModel.modelName} Error: ${errFind.message}`);
        reject(errFind);
      }
      if (collection.length === 0) {
        data.map(person => {
          const newPerson = Object.assign({phone_ids: []}, person);
          person.phone_numbers.map(phone => {
            // successfully seeded commonPhone collection
            commonPhone.addNew(phone, (errPhone, newPhone) => {
             if (errPhone) {
              console.log(`${commonPhone.modelName} Error: ${errPhone.message}`);
               reject(errPhone);
              }
              resolve(newPhone);
              // newPerson does show newPhone.id added to array
              newPerson.phone_ids.push(newPhone.id);
            });
          })
            //////////////// PROBLEM IS HERE ////////////////
            // the array for person's phone_ids is empty?!?!?!
            console.log('PhoneIds: ' + JSON.stringify(newPerson.phone_ids));
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out after two days. The solution may be unique but I think it will be helpful for anyone involved with mapping **ES6 promises** and dealing with mongoose models that have references derived from these **ES6 promises**, so I have been quite detailed about a solution.

> **I. Scenario:**
>
> 1.The PersonModel has a collection phone_ids from the PhoneModel.
>
> 2.The PhoneModel requires a country_id and has a country_code.
>
> 3.The CountryModel has a country._id property that the PhoneModel needs and a country_code.

**II. The Easy Part:**

In my redux actions that I have as api calls, here are the **Country get method** and **Phone addNew method**.

**a. country actions ...**

```
import {CountryRefModel} from '../../../models/_repo.models.api';

module.exports {
 .....
  // need country name too, Canada/US/Carribean Is. have same country_code
  getIdByCountryCode: (countryName, countryCode) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      CountryRefModel.findOne({name: countryName, country_code: countryCode }, 
         {_id: 1}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`${CountryModel.modelName} getIdByCountryCode Error: ${err.message}`);
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
  },
 .....
}
```

**a. phone actions ...**

```
import {PhoneModel} from '../../../models/_repo.models.api';
import * as refCountry from '../../_reference/country/country.reference.actions.api';

module.exports {
 ....
  addNew: (phone) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      refCountry.getIdByCountryCode(phone.country.name, phone.country.country_code)
        // using then method as country action get method
        // is already a promise
        .then(returnValue => {
        PhoneModel.create({
          _id: phone.id,
          country_id: returnValue,
          type: phone.type,
          isMain: phone.isMain ? phone.isMain : false,
          area_code: phone.area_code,
          prefix: phone.prefix,
          suffix: phone.suffix,
          vanity_number: phone.vanity_number ? phone.vanity_number : null
        }, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(`${PersonModel.modelName} addNew Error: ${err.message}`);
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve(result);
        });
      });
    });
  },
 ....
}
```

> **II. Dicey Part:**
>
> The person actions has seed and addNew methods for what I need to do.
>
> 1. I need to map thru the people,
> 2. Map thru their phones,
>
>    a. get the country_id for each phone
>
>    b. add each phone to the phone collection
>
>    c. pass the respective phone._id's to the person
> 3. Add a new person to the collection.

**a. person actions ....**

> The difficult part that took me a while to figure out was the seed
>   method.
>
> Points to consider:
>
> 1. Assigning your mappings to a variable.
> 2. Since the phone action's addNew does the CountryModel search in addition to adding a new phone, I only need to call it's addNew method in the mapping.
> 3. I then call the addNew method with the same module, via module.exports.addNew'

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {PersonModel} from '../../../models/_repo.models.api';
import {addNew} from '../../_common/communication/phone.common.actions.api';

const data = require('../../../seed/_common/people/person.seed.api.js').getData();

function seedDatabase() {
  PersonModel.find({}, (errFind, collection) => {
    if (errFind) {
      console.log(`${PersonModel.modelName} Seed Error: ${errFind.message}`);
    }
    if (collection.length === 0) {
      const updatedPerson = data.map(person => {
          person.id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
          const phoneIds = [];
          const updatePhones = person.phone_numbers.map(phone => {
            phone.id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
            phoneIds.push(phone.id);
            return addNew(phone);
          });
          return module.exports.addNew(person, phoneIds);
        });
      });
      // Just an example of taking the promises further
      //   return LocationModel.addNew(person.id);
    }
  });
}
```

---

```
module.exports = {

  seed: () => seedDatabase(),

  ....

  addNew: (person, phoneIds) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      person.phone_ids = (phoneIds);
      PersonModel.create({
        prefix: person.prefix,
        fName: person.fName,
        mName: person.mName,
        lName: person.lName,
        suffix: person.suffix,
        profDes: person.profDes,
        gender: person.gender,
        email: person.email,
        phone_ids: person.phone_ids,
        lang_key: person.lang_key
      }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`${PersonModel.modelName} addNew Error: ${err.message}`)
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      })
    })
  },

 ....
}
```

As usual, everything in documentation is overly simplified and not abundantly clear on real world scenarios. Hope this helps people!